# Permission Set Group stuck on Updating status

Tags: apex

We deploy builds from Gearset and have never seen this issue before. The stuck permission set group is on our production ORG and all new/refreshed ORGs - new sandboxes will go into UPDATING within minutes of creation. It's always the same permission set group and because of the updating state, we can't delete or alter it. The permission set group never leaves the updating state.

[image: Screenshot]

(Edited with screenshot)

Comment: what do you mean by 'updating'?  Can you use [edit] and post a screenshot?  Have you contacted Gearset support (which is excellent BTW; my org is a Gearset customer)

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to contact salesforce if it never leaves the updating state.

Comment: I would debug this by cloning then selective reduction, start removing one PS at a time from the PSG to see which is the culprit; then examine the offending PS.  It could be a specific permission that causes SFDC to wait on some other event that never happens

Answer (score 3):

From what you've posted there it sounds like it's going to be something stalling at the Salesforce side, but we could certainly look into it from our side for you to see if there's anything in the logs.

The best way to get in touch would be through the chat (bottom right) on https://gearset.com/ - you'll get a reply pretty quickly if you're in office hours UK time, plus we have a smaller number of staff working until around 2200 GMT.

Even if it turns out to be a Salesforce issue, I'm hoping to give you whatever information you need to feed back to Salesforce support.

Valerio (Gearset CS team)